# Is it a good idea to refresh csrf token when submitting form with ajax?

Tags: php, laravel, csrf-token

I want to extend my CSRF token expiration. I know [laravel-caffeine](https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-caffeine) but the token still expired if page is idle for too long.(eg. 24+ hours)

So I come up with an idea that retrieve latest csrf token first with ajax GET method then submit form with this refreshed token.

But I'm not sure if there are some security concerns. For example, assuming that the latest csrf token can be gotten at http://example.com/get_csrf and the adversary can visit this URL too. I wonder whether the adversary can exploit it and make the csrf protection broken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes your concerns are correct. The token is there to prevent other websites to create a request to your site with the session of the victim. Making the token requestable via ajax might create a problem if that can be done from the attacking website.

Comment: But what if the adversary makes a crawler that parse csrf token in meta tag and attach it to malicious POST request? Is it different from the situation I mentioned in my question?

Comment: Good question! I actually don't know the answer just now, you might be on to something or we are overlooking something. Might make a PoC for this problem to test it. Or it relies on Same Origin Policy

Comment: OK, thanks for your reply, now I have learnt more after read the article you posted. As I understand it, the token-based csrf protection is just a workaround rather than a perfect solution in practice. Maybe the most reliable way is still the traditional user/password authentication.

Comment: That's not totally correct, a better conclusion is: **CSRF-tokens prevent malicious request through xhr from another site, which would abuse the user's session in their own browser. This token will only be protected if you also enable Same Origin Policy, as otherwise it still can be stolen**

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to secure the `/get_csrf` route by:

1. saving the `csrf_token()` server side when the form is served and keep it in a column in the users table:

```php
//in your controller

public function showMyForm(){
    $user=auth()->user();
    $user->last_csrf=csrf_token(); // save the csrf token
    $user->save(); //persist to database

    return view('myform');
}
```

2. have your get_csrf route verify the old token and return the new one:

```php
//in your other controller (Route::get('/get_csrf','Controller@getCSRF');)

public function getCSRF(Request $request){
    $user=auth()->user();
    $old_user_token=$user->last_csrf;
    $old_client_token=$request->current_token;
    if ($old_client_token && $old_user_token==$old_client_token){

        // it's a match, update the token in the users table and send the new one
        $user->last_csrf=csrf_token();
        $user->save();
        return csrf_token();
    }

    //no match, tell the client he is unauthorized to get the new csrf token
    abort(401);
}
```

3. ajax GET with the page's current csrf as payload: (using jquery here but you don't need to)

```php
$.ajax({
    url:'/get_csrf',
    method:'POST',
    dataType:"json",
    headers:{
        // have the server treat the request as GET
        'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'GET' 
    },
    data:{
        // send the page's current csrf in the payload
        current_token:document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content') 
    },
    success(data){

        // this is whatever the server sent back as the current csrf for this session
        new_csrf=data; 

        // update the page's csrf
        document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').setAttribute('content',new_csrf);

        //update any _token fields
        document.querySelectorAll('input[name="_token"]').forEach(function(csrf_field){

            csrf_field.setAttribute('value',new_csrf);

        });


    },
    error(response){
        // error handling. maybe console.log(response) here to see what happened?
    }
});
```

4. Submit your form as you usually would.

Answer (score 0):

If the attacks are doing by iframe, a js code can take screenshot of victim's iframe than parse csrf token and than possible to use for another request(theoretically).